# can not restart samba

Tags: 10.04, samba, restart

I installed samba `sudo apt-get install samba`.

then I made configuration but when i write :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/samba restart

message appears " command not found "
```

and when I write `ls /etc/init.d`  I didn't find samba .

solutions tested :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/smbd restart

sudo /etc/init.d/nmbd restart

sudo service samba restart
```

and re-install samba

can you hint me please .

note : my os is  ubuntu10.4 LTS

Answer (score 7):

`sudo /etc/init.d/smbd restart`

> Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
>   utility, e.g. **service smbd restart**
>
> Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
>   Upstart job, you may also use the stop(8) and then start(8) utilities,
>   e.g. **stop smbd** ; **start smbd**. The restart(8) utility is also available.
>
> **smbd stop**/waiting
>
> **smbd start**/running, process 7831

So the commands to start/stop samba:

```
sudo stop smbd
sudo start smbd
```

---

For systemd related systems (ie. Ubuntu 16.04):

```
systemctl start smbd.service
systemctl stop smbd.service
```

Comment: as of Ubuntu 16.04 no such thing as /etc/init.d/smbd (and I do have working samba shares... or is it cifs, and hence... ?)

Comment: 16.04 uses systemd so you need the equivalent for samba using `systemctl`. Likely `systemctl start/stop/restart samba`.

Comment: No `samba`, no `smbd` to be found.  `systemctl list-unit-files | grep ...` and grepping for `sm` and `sa` reveals nothing relevant. (Though samba shares do work for me! Just want to deal with a changed smb.conf)

Comment: typo. it is smdb :)

Comment: No luck with nothing :-/  `sudo systemctl restart smdb.service` - `Failed to restart smdb.service: Unit smdb.service not found.`

Comment: It is the correct command, You need to investigate why it fails. It also should tell you "See 'systemctl status smbd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details" ;-)

Comment: Also after correting smbd to smdb again ;-) I get `systemctl status smdb.service | 
   ● smdb.service, Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)| Active: inactive (dead)` — I start suspecting, Ubuntu 16 somehow integrated samba services elsewhere. This would also explain, why certain smb.conf changes change nothing, even after reboot [don't work as expected](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137192/156470), despite the share service itself perfectly working...

Answer (score 2):

if you have installted samba package.
you can find smbd, nmbd in the folder(/etc/init.d)

if not, it mean that your installation failed.

if yes, you can start the service via --

```
sudo /etc/init.d/smbd start
sudo /etc/init.d/nmbd start
```

or

```
sudo service smbd start
sudo service nmbd start
```